# How to replace do while loop , by for loop or while loop?

Tags: c, for-loop, while-loop, do-while

Here is my code, how could I replace do while by for loop or while loop? What should I change?

```
int main() {
  int a;
  do {
    printf("\nEnter 1 to continue: ");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    if (a==1){
      function=initial(function);
      break;
    } else {
      function=final(function);
    }
  } while (a!=1);
}
```

Comment: The break statement for the case when the user will enter 1 contradicts the phrase "\nEnter 1 to continue: ".:)

Comment: why do you want to change it?

Comment: The `break;` makes no sense together with `} while (a!=1);`

Comment: And the function name `final` makes no sense as the loop continues after `final` but stops after `initial`. Very confusing

Answer (score 0):

A for loop is not suitable for this, you do not iterate over anything (you could still use one tho if you really wanted to).

To use a while loop, initialize `a` to `0`:

```
int a = 0;
while(a != 1){
    ...
}
```

For the for loop:

```
int a = 0;
for(;a != 1;){
    ...
}
```

But none of this is relevant since you just break out of the loop as soon as `a` equals `1` anyway.

Comment: In the for-loop I would move `int a = 0` into the for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

I found it hard to fight the problem of a busy loop after entering a letter: your scanf reads nothing because there is no digit, but the letter is still there in the input.

So the screen gets flooded with "Enter 1 to continue", and you enter "1", even though you rather want it to stop, but only ctrl-c helps.

If you really want the integer "1" or "+1" or "001" as test (and not e.g. first occurence of letter '1'), then you have to read the whole line (= what the user confirmed by enter) as string and convert it to integer.

This uses `%ms` format - m like mem allocation. I put it in a function so it fits in the while() condition. Otherwise it is just `while(1)` or `for(;;)` with a break.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *scanf_line1(char *line) {
        printf("Enter 1 to continue: ");
        scanf("%ms", &line);
        return line;
}
int main() {
    int loop = 0;
    char *line;

    while(atoi(scanf_line1(line)) != 1)
        loop++;
    
    printf("OK, continuing after %d extra loops\n", loop);
}
```

An impression:

```
$ ./a.out
Enter 1 to continue: -1
Enter 1 to continue: +1
OK, continuing after 1 extra loops
$ ./a.out
Enter 1 to continue: 111
Enter 1 to continue: r
Enter 1 to continue: rrrrrrrrr1
Enter 1 to continue: rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr 1
Enter 1 to continue: OK, continuing after 4 extra loops
$ ./a.out
Enter 1 to continue: 5 4 3 2 1
Enter 1 to continue: Enter 1 to continue: Enter 1 to continue: Enter 1 to continue: OK, continuing after 4 extra loops
$ ./a.out
Enter 1 to continue: 2 00000000000000000000001
Enter 1 to continue: OK, continuing after 1 extra loops
```

Suddenly it works with hidden numbers, instead of crashing. Just the repeated message for each non-1 word in the line.